# Horrific SVN merge - is it possible to import repo to Git and use Git to merge?

Tags: svn, git

As above, is it possible to export an SVN repo with history into a new Git repo and then use Git to do a merge from a branch back into the trunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you've merged, what then? Do you want to import the code back into SVN? You'll lose all the merge information.

you can migrate to git - there are answers already for that on SO, and you can use git-svn to put sort of a git front-end to a svn repo.

Comment: Why merging in git-svn and pushing back to svn wouldn't work? Doesn't it keep merge info?

Comment: If the main repo is SVN, my guess is "merge information" isn't the goal. SVN doesn't traffic in such stuff anyway. He probably just wants a cleanly merged tree.